# How can I change maxlength parameter to validate a textarea considering only the letters and not the spaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using jQuery validate a form and I need to display a textarea with minlength 1 letter and maxlength 500 letters.

How can I change maxlength parameter to validate a textarea considering only the letters and not the spaces?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to block user after *X* letters you should use `keydown` instead of `keyup` proposed in answers

Comment: You need to create your own custom rule

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own custom rule, see e.g:

```
$.validator.addMethod('customLength', function (value, elm, param) {
    //Your Validation rule here    
    return elm.value.replace(/ /g,'').length <= 500; // return bool 
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            "name": {
                required: true,
                customLength: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": {
                required: "Please, enter a name",
                customLength: 'Custom error message!'
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on('keyup','textarea',function(){
   if($(this).val() != ""){
     var textarea = $(this).val().replace(/ /g,'');
     var length = textarea.length;

     if(length > 500){
       alert('Limit reached');
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: @Haryia what are you getting in the output? Any error in the console?

Comment: no errors, but the form is submitted without counting the control

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('keyup','textarea',function(){
     var textarea = $(this).val().replace(/ /g,'');
     var newLength = textarea.length;
//set to new max length (basically 500 + whitespaces' length)
 $(this).attr('maxlength',500 +($(this).val().length - newLength) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jquery-validate` that you mention. Then please add another `js` that is `additional-methods.min.js` which have a extra capability to handle custom logic

**HTML page**

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-validate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formID" name="formID" method="post">
            <textarea id="textareaID" name="textareaID" ></textarea>
            <input id="submitBtn" type="submit">
        </form>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#formID").validate({
                    rules: {
                        textareaID:{
                            required:true,
                            checkLenght:true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        textareaID:{
                             required:'Please enter',
                             checkLenght:'msg..'
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $.validator.addMethod("checkLenght", function(value, element){ 
                var count = (value.match(/\d/g) || []).length;

                if(count == 0 || count >500)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;

                /*here is example regex you can write as per you requirement*/
            });
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For your further refrence : https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Hope my explanation is works for you.

Comment: I can understand but it does not working. 

I Use that code:

 $j('#form-concorso').validate({
            rules: {
                
               textareaID:{
                 required:true,
                 checkLenght:true
               }
              },

              messages: {
                textareaID:{
                required:'Please enter',
                checkLenght:'msg..'
               }
             }
});

and 

$.validator.addMethod("checkLenght", function(value, element){

  return elm.value.replace(/ /g,'').length <= 500;

});

Comment: The code is too long so I create a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/haryia/rc8fka3h/

Thanks!

Comment: please put your `addMethod` function outside from `ready` event

Comment: your `script` code is not proper that you done in fiddle

Comment: I put the code out of ready function, but the situation doesn't change :(

Comment: open browser in `inspect` mode check any other `jquery` error occured or not. And also verify your code properly